# FileInputStream is not ending in java

Tags: java, file, io, stream

I was practicing using byte streams in Java when I came across this code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class CopyBytes_practice {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream f=null;
    FileOutputStream fo=null;
    int c;
    int d;
    try {
        f=new FileInputStream("a.png");
        fo=new FileOutputStream("b.png");
        c=f.read();
        while(c != -1){
            fo.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (f != null) {
            f.close();
        }
        if (fo != null) {
            fo.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I used a 35kb a.png file and a 0kb b.png file to execute the code, but the code ran forever - the size of b.png reached 905mb before I stopped the JVM manually.

I am confused, why is the end of file status not returned? Is it not supported in Binary files, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You missed something important

```
c=f.read(); // <-- Read in one byte ...
while(c != -1){
  fo.write(c);
  c=f.read(); // <--- Add this, to Read in the next byte (or -1)...
}
```

So you were infinitely looping, and writing the first `byte` from your source.

Comment: That solved it... but i don't get it, can you please explain what `c=f.read();` did???

Comment: You were reading only the first byte of your source file and writing it forever. It'd never be "-1" so it wouldn't ever stop. Calling `c=f.read` keeps going further on the source file till its end.

Comment: ohk, i get it now, that means writing `while((c=f.read()) != -1)` could have made my day, ryt? thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because it's an infinite loop, you need to tell the loop where to stop.In other words, the loop should keep reading until it reaches the end of the file.

```
 while ((c= f.read()) != -1){
    fo.write(c);
 }
```

Comment: because c was still equal to the first byte value, read() returns -1 when it reaches the end of the file. Every time you call read(), it jumps to the next chunk @user2869389